# Apache and different document roots based on url

Tags: apache-http-server

Is it possible to have multiple document roots for the same domain name but with a different language flag?

Example:

- `www.example.com/en` and e.g. `www.example.com/en/about-us`, etc. goes to `/www/site_new`.
- `www.example.com/de` and `www.example.com/de/uber-uns`, etc. goes to `/www/site_old`.

Someone mentioned symlinks, but I can't figure out how to achieve this using the above scenario.

Comment: Assuming symlinks: I would setup my www.domain.com document root to be /var/www, I may then have a link /var/www/en pointing to /path/to/my/en/website.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have multiple `DocumentRoot` directives for the same domain name but with a different language flag?

As far as I am aware, the strict answer to this is "no" (that is, you can't have multiple `DocumentRoot` directives for a given domain name). However, you can create subdomains as virtual hosts and give them their own `DocumentRoot`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com en.example.com

DocumentRoot "/www/site_new"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName de.example.com
#ServerAlias www.example.com

DocumentRoot "/www/site_old"

</VirtualHost>
```

**Mapping URLs To Folders With Alias**

[Using the Apache `Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html) could provide a solution to your example:

```
Alias "/en" "/www/site_new"
Alias "/en/about-us" "/www/site_new"

Alias "/de" "/www/site_old"
Alias "/de/uber-uns" "/www/site_old"
```

In this instance:

- `www.example.com/en` and `www.example.com/en/about-us` would map to `/www/site_new`
- `www.example.com/de` and `www.example.com/de/uber-uns` would map to `/www/site_old`.

> Someone mentioned symlinks, but I can't figure out how to achieve this with the scenario outlined above.

You can use symlinks as the targets for `Alias` <sup>1</sup>.

Otherwise, using *only* symlinks, I think you would run into confusion with subfolders. For example (if I am not mistaken):

- In your `DocumentRoot`, `/en` would need to be a symlink to `/www/site_new`.
- In `/www/site_new`, `/about-us` would also need to be a symlink to `/www/site_new`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *With Apache on Windows, this can overcome permissions issues with folders located outside the `DocumentRoot` given in `httpd.conf`.*

---